# Except statement in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

Code from Django tutorial:

```
try:
    selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
# The rest of code...
```

Why we have two these exceptions here: `KeyError` and `Choice.DoesNotExist`?

Isn't they are equal?
What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KeyError` may be raised by `request.POST['choice']`. It's a Python error for dictionaries raised when you try to access a key that doesn't exist.

`DoesNotExist` is a Django framework error for the DB interface raised when you try to get an object from the database and it doesn't exist.

`Choice.DoesNotExist` inherits from `DoesNotExist` but only for the `Choice` model, and thus is raised when you do something like `Choice.objects.get(...)` and the instance does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If `request.POST['choice']` fails which will generate `KeyError`.

Another one is:

```
exception ObjectDoesNotExist

    The DoesNotExist exception is raised when an object is not found for the given parameters of a query.
```

Now, if you don't put `KeyError`, the system will raise the error, and your `except` will be useless as `KeyError` is not captured and viceversa.